# Set the position of the Xtick labels matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to shift the x ticks labels downwards in this figure:[image: fig]

I'm not sure how to do this?

This is the script I'm using:

```
y=[0.5093 0.8526 0.9171];
x=[0 1600 1100];
hand =plot(y, 'ob-');
set(gca, 'XTick',1:3, 'XTickLabel',{'no interference' '1600' '1100'})
set(hand, 'LineWidth', 4);
set(hand, 'MarkerSize', 30);
set(findobj('type','text'),'FontSize',25);
set(gca,'FontSize',25);
set(findobj('type','axes'),'FontSize',25);
h=get(gca,'Title');
set(h,'FontSize',20);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Distance between axis label and axis in MATLAB figure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966770/distance-between-axis-label-and-axis-in-matlab-figure)

Comment: @Shai I want to move the X-tick labels downwards not the X-axis label.

Comment: One option: this [mathworks solution](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-15TK6/index.html?solution=1-15TK6) shows how to put labels at custom positions, by defining them as text (it also rotates them).  Just add an offset to the ypos (2nd param in `text()` function call).

Comment: @Bonlenfum will you please post an answer using my script?

Comment: you might find this fex useful: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3486-xticklabelrotate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the example from this [mathworks solution](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-15TK6/index.html?solution=1-15TK6), you can use the `text` function to add labels in any position you wish.

Increase the value of `delta` for a larger gap between x tick labels and x axis.

EDIT: Added custom control of `ytick`s: the value of `stp` changes the step between each tick.  Obviously a more general solution would identify the end-points of the tick range automatically as well.

```
figure(1), clf

% set data as your example
y=[0.5093 0.8526 0.9171];
x=[0 1600 1100];
Xt=1:length(x);
hand =plot(y, 'ob-');
set(gca, 'XTick',Xt);

stp=0.05;
Yt=0.5:stp:0.95;
set(gca, 'ytick', Yt)

% Reduce the size of the axis so that all the labels fit in the figure.
pos = get(gca,'Position');
set(gca,'Position',[pos(1), .2, pos(3) .7])

ax = axis; % Current axis limits
axis(axis); % Set the axis limit modes (e.g. XLimMode) to manual
Yl = ax(3:4); % Y-axis limits
Xl = ax(1:2);

% Place the text labels -- the value of delta modifies how far the labels 
% are from the axis.
delta=0.1;
t = text(Xt, Yl(1)*ones(1,length(x))-delta, {'no interference' '1600' '1100'});
%set(t, 'HorizontalAlignment','left','VerticalAlignment','top')
set(t, 'HorizontalAlignment','center','VerticalAlignment','middle')

% Remove the default labels
set(gca,'XTickLabel','')

% and continue with your other settings as required
set(hand, 'LineWidth', 4);
set(hand, 'MarkerSize', 30);
set(findobj('type','text'),'FontSize',25);
set(gca,'FontSize',25);
set(findobj('type','axes'),'FontSize',25);
h=get(gca,'Title');
set(h,'FontSize',20);
```

The `text` function has [lots of options](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/text.html) that you can configure.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The scale of the Y-axis changed and I want it as shown in the figure. Your solution skips the .005 ticks of the y-axis, so what appears (0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9) and what I want is (0.5,0.55,0.6,0.65,...)

Answer (score 2):

I think what most people want is something that works in 2-3 lines of code, nevermind-ing a quick&dirty approach.

This is undocumented (credits go to [here](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/customizing-histogram-plots)) but just works:

```matlab
    % adjust ticklabels away from axes
    a=gca;
    a.XRuler.TickLabelGapOffset = 8;
    a.YRuler.TickLabelGapOffset = 8;
```

tested with Matlab 2019a